# How do you solve $2x + y = 40$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We're starting to learn this at school, and I really have no idea at all, how to do it! Please someone help me! My dad did it and showed me how to do it, but I still have no idea what-so-ever!

Comment: Give more informations please, does $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ or $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: I suspect you mean make$y$ the subject otherwise you could fix one variable and work out the corresponding one for the other.

Comment: That is exactly what I meant!

Comment: Then $y=40-2x$ is the answer. Do you see how?

Comment: @Shahmir I shocked that you see how considering if just gave you the answer. This type of thing can easily be googled or found on any maths text book. Plus you need to provide you thoughts or your attempts at the question, regardless how silly they may seem. It at least provides some evidence that you at least tried something.

Comment: I tried, but nothing made sense to me! I tried my go-to website mathisfun.com, but again nothing!

Comment: @Shahmir u can't just say nothing made sense. Be specific what doesn't make sense. If you say nothing, does that mean you dont know what an equality means? or what the number 40 is? or what variables x and y mean? Or what the question statement is? there are a lot of things that we could explain but without you providing your own thoughts, it just feels you want us to give you the answer (or at least it not clear you did any thinking yourself or research). I usually post resources I checked before posting my question and explaining why they didn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Shahmir you could even ask to clarify what 2x is, I remember that I was once confused about what multiplying things was and didn't realize that it was commutative, so I was asked to simplify 2x + x3 and I didn't know 3x = x3....so yea, just be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose $x$ to be anything, and you will always fine a $y$ that works .

try it

let $x = 1$ then $$2 \times 1 + y = 40 \implies y = 40 -2 = 38$$

Let's do it one more time

let $x = 2$ then $$2 \times 2 + y = 40 \implies y = 40 -4 = 36$$

and so on

Answer (score 0):

Two unknowns and one equation has infinite solutions,so it has infinite solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This is one equation with two variables, so the solution (x,y) won't be a single ordered set.
What is usually meant by solve in this situation is to find each variable in terms of the others, ie. x in terms of y and y in terms of x.

let x be anything then $y = 40 - 2x$

let y be anything then $x = \frac{(40 - y )}{2}$